# Битовые операции, проверка битов

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Использую битовые операции для опций в GUI, возникла необходимость проверить установлен ли хоть 1 бит. Правильно ли я понимаю что если число равно 0, то значит все биты находятся в сброшенном состоянии? Не понятно как быть с последним битом который отвечает положительное это число или отрицательное. 
Используется unsigned int.
Можно пройтись циклом по всем битам, но может в этом нет необходимости и достаточно сравнивать просто с 0? Может ли возникнуть ситуация что будет -0 и +0 бит установлен но все же это ноль.

Comment: Если используется `unsigned int` то в нём по определению нету знакового бита, поэтому можно смело сравнивать значение с нулём.

Comment: В signed int тоже не может быть отрицательного нуля. Это только в вещественных числах: double/float - может быть `-0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что для целых чисел обычно используется не просто бит, отвечающий за знак (как в числах с плавающей точкой например), а специальное представление [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), при котором не возникает ситуации с отрицательным нулем. В такой нотации например выставление верхнего бита в байте `10000000` дает число `-128`, а не `-0`.